# Split the String on second time if exist and otherwise split on the first time

Tags: java, string

Hi i have a string "I am Anna. I am from California". I want to cut the string at second "am", if second "am" exist.otherwise i want to split at first "am". I am now using split method and tried pattern matching.  Please help

```
   String mydata = "I am Anna. I am from California";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("I(.*?) A");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
    if (matcher.find())
    {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

Comment: show what you have attempted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split after `am` where there are no occurrences of `am` in the remaining input:

```
String[] parts = mydata.split("(?<=\\bam\\b)(?!.*\\bam\\b)");
```

If you just want the first part:

```
String intro = mydata.split("(?<=\\bam\\b)(?!.*\\bam\\b)")[0];
```

Comment: when i tried this i am getting input as output.

Comment: Thank you, I am not familiar with the regex.

Comment: how can i get the last part after the split "from California"?

Comment: `String outro = mydata.split("(?<=\\bam\\b)(?!.*\\bam\\b)")[1]`?